# Guitar pitch detection

Tags: fft, pitch, real-time

I try to develop a guitar game in android platform.

And I need to do the real-time pitch detection of guitar chord.

I will get the input from the microphone, and then analyze the input (the input playing which kind of guitar string/chord).

I find two kinds of method that I can use, one is YIN, another one is FFT.

Which method can get better performance and exact result?

Comment: chords are, *how shall we say?*, a **female-canine**.  dunno how [melodyne](http://www.celemony.com/en/melodyne/what-can-melodyne-do) does it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pitch detection of guitar chord"? Pitch detection is the detection of a single pitch, the other task would be "chord identification". The latter is immensely difficult and you would also need to define what it exactly is that you want to identify: "just" the type of chord (e.g., an E chord), or the exact inversion, i.e., where and on which strings was that E chord played.

Comment: I will get the input from the microphone, and then analyze the input (the input playing which kind of guitar string/chord), How can I do it? @Matt L.

Comment: "String" or "chord", that is the question!

Comment: That mean chord estimation is nearly imposible to do it? @Matt L.

Comment: If you're not an expert in signal/audio processing, I think you should start with (single) pitch detection, that's hard enough to do well. Identifying chords is still a much harder task.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous.  Chord, pitch and frequency detection/estimation are very different things.  Bare FFT magnitudes are really bad at guitar pitch modeling.  YIN is a better monophonic pitch estimator.  Polyphonic chord estimation is vastly more difficult, and may or may not even be possible, depending on your input data or time/pitch accuracy requirements (exactly what is your "exact result"?) plus any computational limitations ("real time" latency requirements, CPU performance/cores/GPUs available, etc.)

Comment: If I try to do polyphonic chord estimation, what kind of method/algorithm can possible to do it? @hotpaw2

Comment: See: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~klap/iiro/ and other research papers published over at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Society_for_Music_Information_Retrieval conference.

Comment: I will go to read the paper, Thank you for your answer.